# sql join query returns same row multiple times

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, join, firebird

```
    select distinct "CARIHR"."BLCHKODU", "CARIHR"."BLCRKODU",
       "CARIHR"."OZEL_KOD", "CARIHR"."EVRAK_NO",
       "CARIHR"."ISLEM_TURU", "CARIHR"."TARIH",
       "CARIHR"."BORC", "CARIHR"."TAHSILAT",
       "CARIHR"."ACIKLAMA", "CARIHR"."VADE",
       "CARIHR"."FATURA_HAREKETI",
       "CARIHR"."VF_UYGULA", "CARIHR"."HR_ESLEME",
       "CARIHR"."TAKIP", "FATURA"."BLFTKODU",
       "FATURA"."BLCRKODU" as "FATURA_BLCRKODU",
       "FATURA"."BLCH1KODU", "FATURA"."BLCH2KODU",
       "FATURA"."TARIHI", "FATURA"."KAP_FATURA",
       "FATURA"."KAP_FATTUR",
       "FATURA"."ACIKLAMA" as "FATURA_ACIKLAMA",
       "FATURA"."TOPLAM", "FATURA"."TOPLAM_KDV",
       "FATURA"."KDV_HARIC",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI_TOPLAMI",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI1", "FATURA"."KESINTI2",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI3", "FATURA"."KESINTI5",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI4",
       "FATURA"."VADE" as "FATURA_VADE",
       "FATURA"."KDV_DURUMU",
       "FATURA"."ALIS_SATIS_MUSTAHSIL",
       "FATURA"."TAKIP" as "FATURA_TAKIP",
       "FATURA"."KESILECEK_1",
       "FATURA"."KESILECEK_2",
       "FATURA"."KESILECEK_3",
       "FATURA"."FATURANOT",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI1ORAN",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI2ORAN",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI3ORAN",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI4ORAN",
       "FATURA"."KESINTI5ORAN",
       "FATURAHR"."BLFHKODU",
       "FATURAHR"."BLFTKODU" as "FATURAHR_BLFTKODU",
       "FATURAHR"."BLSTKODU",
       "FATURAHR"."BLSHKODU", "FATURAHR"."CINSI",
       "FATURAHR"."BIRIMI", "FATURAHR"."MIKTARI",
       "FATURAHR"."FIYAT", "FATURAHR"."ARATUTAR",
       "FATURAHR"."TOPLAMTUTAR",
       "FATURAHR"."KDV_ORANI",
       "FATURAHR"."KDV_TUTAR", "FATURAHR"."NEM",
       "FATURAHR"."KESINTI_TOPLAMI" as "FATURAHR_KESINTI_TOPLAMI",
       "CARI"."CARI_KODU", "CARI"."TICARI_UNVANI",
       "CARI"."ADI_SOYADI", "CARI"."ADRESI",
       "CARI"."VERGI_DAIRESI", "CARI"."VERGI_NO",
       "CARI"."ILI", "CARI"."ILCESI",
       "CARI"."GRUBU", "CARI"."EMAIL",
       "CARI"."CEP_TEL", "CARI"."TELEFON",
       "CARI"."FAKS", "CARI"."OZELKOD_1",
       "CARI"."OZELKOD_2", "CARI"."OZELKOD_3",
       "CARI"."KAYIT_TARIHI",
       "CARI"."OZEL_TARIHI", "CARI"."TC_KIMLIK",
       "CARI"."BAGKUR_NO", "CARI"."KOYU",
       "CARI"."NOTU",
       "CARI"."BLCRKODU" as "CARI_BLCRKODU"
  from ((("CARIHR" "CARIHR"
  left
  join "FATURA" "FATURA"
       on ("FATURA"."BLCH1KODU" = "CARIHR"."BLCHKODU"))
  left
  join "FATURAHR" "FATURAHR"
       on ("FATURAHR"."BLFTKODU" = "FATURA"."BLFTKODU"))
  left
  join "CARI" "CARI"
       on ("CARI"."BLCRKODU" = "CARIHR"."BLCRKODU"))
```

I am using DevExpress XtraReport and this is my sql query. When i run this query my 104th row returns 20 times and 59th row returns 5 times etc. I tried a lot of things to solve this but im not good at sql join and i didnt find anything. I cant solve this.

Comment: Duplicates with distinct would imply differences in at least one of the columns. Are you sure that EVERY column is the same int hese duplicates?

Comment: FATURAHR is mine table which stores my invoice activities so if i join this table my returning rows duplicate how much activity i have got. Every Column isnt same its returning everything same except FATURAHR columns.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT is for the whole selected row, not just for the first column.

Comment: yes i know but select distinct doesnt matter.

Comment: Can you please clarify your comments, if the columns from the FATURAHR table are not the same, then they are distinct are they not?

Comment: They are not distinct. Im getting ID 104 20 times and i tried distinct to only get one but i cant make it :(

Comment: DISTINCT works on the complete row. So if there are 20 records for ID 104 with different BLFHKODU (for instance) then you get 20 rows of course. If you don't want this, which of the BLFHKODU etc. do you want? Please edit your request and show the twenty rows you get and the one row you want to get instead.

Comment: i want to get unique BLCHKODU not like 20 times i want to get it 1 time.

Comment: just wanna get all CARIHR's and another tables with have relation CARIHR. A example i will get ID 104 and print it its FATURA to screen after than i will print FATURAHR's related to FATURA

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() and select 1st row from each result that will give you unique result.
Also if you can please provide snap shot of your sample data , i can develop query using row_number()

Comment: here my database. I just wanna get all CARIHR's and another tables with have relation CARIHR. A example i will get ID 104 and print it its FATURA to screen after than i will print FATURAHR's related to FATURA

https://www.solidfiles.com/v/Za8jepN5aNWLA

Comment: i have checked the link , it is showing file is corrupted.
can you please reupload the database so i can check and develop query.